# Export 3DS file with pivot point in Blender

Tags: export, add-on

Hi I've been working with Blender for some time and I can't figure out how to export 3DS with pivot point. I tried exporting 3DS by putting 3D cursor and the object origin, but it doesn't seem to export the pivot point either. Need help on this.

Comment: 3DS file exported from Blender does keep pivot point data, you can confirm this by importing it back into blender, with **Apply Transform** toggled. I think you should look into more settings of that application when you are going to import into it.

Comment: The object origin does exist after exporting, but the pivot point doesn't have any value. Using solely Blender is fine for this case, but other tools/software are using other info for pivot point, which I believe it isn't there in exported 3ds. I tried to check the 3ds export script, the script doesn't export the following chunk in 3ds file: OBJECT_PIVOT, 0xB013
POS_TRACK_TAG, 0xB020
ROT_TRACK_TAG, 0xB021
SCL_TRACK_TAG, 0xB022 The author mentioned that the particular code crashes Blender, so they are commented out. I wonder what happened on that. I need those values for other tools. Any idea?